Rotation Axis Transformation in High RPM Application
I am currently working on designing a go kart powered by a lawnmower engine. From my research, it is a large hassle to turn the engine on its side to have the shaft in the correct axis. Instead, I would like to transform the axis of rotation and then lower the RPM of the engine. Not being a mechanical engineer, I'm very wary of friction. I realize that I could use a crown gear or bevel gears and then a chain and sprocket afterward to achieve this, but I'm leaning towards using a universal joint instead (and keep the chain and sprocket of course), so I don't have to worry about friction. Am I being overcautious about friction/overlooking a better solution? Additionally, I would like to keep costs low, so any ideas about how to keep it inexpensive are appreciated.
Thanks!

you can't change rotation 90 degrees with a U joint.

The usual recommendation is for a maximum of a 3 degree change from one U-joint which would lead to 30 U-joints for your 90 degree turn. In other words, this almost certainly isn't practical. Even if you doubled or tripled the usual recommendation, it would still be impractical.

you could do gear reduction in the vertical orientation and then use chain drive to make the 90 degree transition
